# JaxB: set xsi:type and xmlns:q1 to request object

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jaxb, marshalling

I want my xml to look like this:

```
                <data xsi:type="q1:UniversalLicenseRequest" xmlns:q1="http://integration.elicense.kz/CustomServices/Egov/EgovLicenseSearchService">
                    <q1:PageIndex>0</q1:PageIndex>
                    <q1:PageSize>10</q1:PageSize>
                    <q1:SystemInfo>
                        <q1:MessageId>a62ba0f1-5b3e-4c35-862d-032e9cdcfb68</q1:MessageId>
                        <q1:ChainId>162d9c25-8734-4fef-81d4-22dd5621e36e</q1:ChainId>
                        <q1:MessageDate>2019-01-18T10:00:49.7229311+06:00</q1:MessageDate>
                        <q1:MessageType>Request</q1:MessageType>
                        <q1:SignatureType>None</q1:SignatureType>
                    </q1:SystemInfo>
                    <q1:IinBin>921203350262</q1:IinBin> 
                    <q1:IssueDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                </data>
```

Here is my `UniversalLicenseRequest` class:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "UniversalLicenseRequest", propOrder = {
"iinBin",
"rnn",
"numberNikadUinrd",
"issueDate",
"activityCodes"
 })
public class UniversalLicenseRequest
       extends RequestPageBase
{
@XmlElement(name = "IinBin")
protected String iinBin;
@XmlElement(name = "Rnn")
protected String rnn;
@XmlElement(name = "NumberNikadUinrd")
protected String numberNikadUinrd;
@XmlElement(name = "IssueDate", required = true, nillable = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar issueDate;
@XmlElement(name = "ActivityCodes")
protected String activityCodes;
@XmlElement(name = "SystemInfo")
protected SystemInfo systemInfo;
... getters and setters
```

And here is `SystemInfo` class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SystemInfo", propOrder = {
"messageId",
"chainId",
"messageDate",
"messageType",
"serviceId",
"responseCode",
"additionalInfo",
"senderId",
"digitalSignature",
"signatureType"
})
public class SystemInfo {

@XmlElement(name = "MessageId")
protected String messageId;
@XmlElement(name = "ChainId")
protected String chainId;
@XmlElement(name = "MessageDate", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar messageDate; 
.....
```

Here is the method which creates and sends a request (It is written in Kotlin, but I hope you can understand it):

```
    private fun makeRequest(_iinBin: String, message_id: String): Document {
    val request = kz.esb.elicense.model.UniversalLicenseRequest().apply {
        pageIndex = 0
        pageSize = 10
        systemInfo = SystemInfo().apply {
            messageId = message_id
            messageDate = CalendarUtils.currentXMLGregorianCalendar()
            messageType = MessageType.REQUEST
            signatureType = DigitalSignatureType.NONE
        }
        iinBin = _iinBin
    }

    val document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().apply {
        isNamespaceAware = true
    }.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()

    val jaxbElement = JAXBElement<kz.esb.elicense.model.UniversalLicenseRequest>(QName("http://integration.elicense.kz/CustomServices/Egov/EgovLicenseSearchService", "UniversalLicenseRequest"),
            kz.esb.elicense.model.UniversalLicenseRequest::class.java,
            request)
    val marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(kz.esb.elicense.model.UniversalLicenseRequest::class.java).createMarshaller()
    marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, document)
    return document
}
```

But in the end my request looks like this:

```
 <data              xmlns:ns2="http://integration.elicense.kz/CustomServices/Egov/EgovLicenseSearchService">
                    <SystemInfo>
                        <MessageId>dad59a9c-60ba-4d76-94f2-30918ee5fb4c</MessageId>
                        <MessageDate>2019-09-26T12:43:21.624+06:00</MessageDate>
                        <MessageType>Request</MessageType>
                        <SignatureType>None</SignatureType>
                    </SystemInfo>
                    <PageIndex>0</PageIndex>
                    <PageSize>10</PageSize>
                    <IinBin>971240002363</IinBin>
                    <IssueDate
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </data>
```

**EDIT:**

`makeRequest` method is called as:

```
val request = RequestData().apply {
                data = makeRequest(_iinBin = bin, message_id = message_id).firstChild
            }
```

And `RequestData` class looks like this:

```
   @XmlSeeAlso({
    UniversalLicenseRequest.class,
   })
   public class RequestData
    implements Serializable {

    protected Object data;
```

As you can see `data` field is just an Object. After that I send the message:

```
    val response = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(serviceLocation, request)
```

Comment: Since you are asking us about the `<data>` element, you should show us the JAXB class where that element is defined, because that's where the magic happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB - marshal with xsi:type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30510773/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB: Concrete type information (xsi:type) missing on marshalled XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42131632/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas [JAXB- marshal with xsi:type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510773/jaxb-marshal-with-xsitype) this link helped. Thank you!